Insert with values from existing table
I need to move some values based on expiration date, but unfortunately because the tables are not one to one in number of records I receive an error message when my query is run. I need SQL to be able to assign it's own primary key value because I believe that is where the conflict is coming from.
The error message is:

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ClerkDogHistory'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ClerkDogHistory'. The duplicate key value is (10595).

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Table_records_are_being_moved_TO] ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO [Table_records_are_being_moved_TO] (column1, column2,column3...)
SELECT *
FROM [Table_records_are_being_moved_FROM]
WHERE [expiration_date] between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31';

DELETE FROM [Table_records_are_being_moved_FROM]
WHERE [expiration_date] between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31';

COMMIT;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Table_records_are_being_moved_TO] OFF


Just turn identify insert off and let SQL Server generate its own PK?

@AlwaysLearning I took what OP said to say they are attempting to insert duplicate ids into the new table, and they specifically say they need SQL Server to assign its own ID... rather than the inserted one, because the inserted one is causing duplicates... therefore they shouldn't have identity insert on.

@DaleK the op is already controlling IDENTITY_INSERT in the posted code. The problem is that the source query is trying to insert additional data that would violate the primary key constraint of the target table.

@AlwaysLearning yes and they say that want SQL to be able to assign it's own primary key value - hence they need identity insert to be off not on.

Well, it's often said "don't use SELECT *." This is another reason why. Op needs to specify all of the columns, except for the identity column, when selecting/inserting the data.

@AlwaysLearning of course, OP hasn't suggested they don't know how to do that, just that they need an auto-generated id... they kinda need to clarify what their real issue us tbh.. but as they haven't come back and engaged what can we do.

Hello thank you for all of your comments. I used IDENTITY_INSERT because when I don't it throws the following error "Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table_name' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

The query works as long as there is no duplicate value in the primary key column and it seems that now I am moving more data there are duplicates in that field.

Please use column names instead of *, also remove IDENTITY_INSERT ON, OFF clause. and don't put the Identity column in your query.
Your final query something look like this.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO [Table_records_are_being_moved_TO] (column1, column2,column3...)

SELECT column1, column2,column3... FROM [Table_records_are_being_moved_FROM] WHERE [expiration_date] between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31';

DELETE FROM [Table_records_are_being_moved_FROM] WHERE [expiration_date] between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31';

COMMIT;


What is steric?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for your comment, but not sure what "steric" means can you explain? Also I am using the actual column names in the query I am running. I renamed to column 1, 2 etc for privacy purposes. If you mean steric = this symbol * then yes I have tried replacing with the actual column names but it still throws the duplicate primary key error message as well as using *.

Also when replacing the * with the actual column names it will throw this error "Incorrect syntax near ','." with an indicator on the first column name.

steric = *, and in column names don't add the primary key column in both statement(insert into and select).
